# How to write the following conditional density function?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, density-function

Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independently and identically distributed with probability density function $f(x)$. Let event $A$ be "at least one random variable in $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is greater than $t$". What is $f(x|A)$?

I know that if the event is "$X_1>t$", then I can define the set $\{x:x>t\}$, and write $f(x|X_1>t)=\frac{f(x)\mathbf{1}(x\in \{x:x>t\} )}{Pr(X>t)}$, where $\mathbf{1}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function. I don't know how to extend this formula to find $f(x|A)$, because I don't see how to construct the set in the indicator function.

Comment: Is $f(x|A)$ the pdf of $X_1$ given $A$?

Comment: @whoisit Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:$$f(x)=f(x|A)P(A)+f(x|A^c)P(A^c)\tag1$$and event $A^c=\{X_1,X_2,X_3\leq t\}$ is more convenient to work with than event $A$.

Note that:$$P\left(X_{1}\leq x,A^{c}\right)=\begin{cases}
F\left(x\right)F\left(t\right)^{2} & \text{if }x\leq t\\
F(t)^3 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ so that:$$P\left(X_{1}\leq x\mid A^{c}\right)=\begin{cases}
F\left(x\right)/F\left(t\right) & \text{if }x\leq t\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and:$$f\left(x|A^{c}\right)=\begin{cases}
f\left(x\right)/F\left(t\right) & \text{if }x\leq t\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Applying $(1)$ we then find:$$f\left(x\mid A\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(x\mid A^{c}\right)P\left(A^{c}\right)}{P\left(A\right)}=\begin{cases}
\frac{f\left(x\right)\left(1-F\left(t\right)^{2}\right)}{1-F\left(t\right)^{3}} & \text{if }x\leq t\\
\frac{f\left(x\right)}{1-F\left(t\right)^{3}} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! Just a quick question, intuitively, why $f(x|A)$ is discontinuous at $t$ in general?

Comment: The relation $(1)$ in my answer makes clear that your question is actually the same as: "why is $f(x|A^c)$ discontinuous at $t$?" I think the answer on that is easyer to grasp. It appears that at point $x=t$ this function "jumps" to $0$ (causing discontinuïty).